# Incorporar perfil do Instagram

Tags: instagram-api

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de incorporar um perfil do Instagram, assim como há o Like Button ou o Widget do Twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oficialmente](https://help.instagram.com/513918941996087), só é possível fazer embed de imagens e vídeos, não do perfil inteiro como você quer.

Comment: Existe algum plugin que faça isso? procurei e não achei nada. =/

Comment: @FelipeStoker Sim, http://web.stagram.com/tools/

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte.

```
<iframe id="frame" width="320" height="568" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BxFc58nFwpN/embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Assim você estará criando um iframe que mostra uma postagem especifica do seu perfil.

Infelizmente o instagram não permite que você incorpore a pagina inteira, mas acredito que isso já ajuda bastante.

Mas tem uma forma de reverter isso, se você e do tipo que gosta de gambiara, você pode criar uma pagina, semelhante a o instagram, e usar a própria api do instagram para pegar as fotos/vídeos do seu perfil.

Como por exemplo esse site -> https://web.stagram.com/leomessi

Apenas lembre que no fim do link você deve por o embed, como no exemplo acima.